# Create multiple pages with tables from json file

Tags: pages, rest-api, json, table

I have this problem on Wordpress.
I have a json file with a structure like this

```
{ 
   "obj": [ 
      "obj1": {
         "field1": "..",
         "field2": [
            {
                "field": ""
            }
         ] 
      }, 
      "obj2": {
       "field1": "..",
         "field2": [
            {
                "field": ""
            }
         ] 
     }, 
      ... 
   ]
}
```

Now I need to create a page for each obj in the json by using Wordpress Rest API. I know I can do it, but the problem is that in each page I need to put a table populated with some field of each obj. I can create a page, but I don't know how to put table in that page.

Someone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a one-off job? Does it run from outside WordPress (= you can us the REST API to make pages, or [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/)) or inside WordPress (you can use the normal internal APIs)

Comment: It is a one-off job. I need to create a page for each json object once. The page created will not change

Comment: if you can create the page, it means you can populate it with contents... When you create a page using rest apis, one of the arguments you pass is `content`, described as `The content for the object.` Your table goes in there.